# Passing require.main to path.dirname

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to figure out why

`path.dirname(require.main)`

returns `.` or the path from the root of my application to the main module running, which in this case are the same—I'm running a gulp task defined in `gulpfile.js` at the root of my application.

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_p) say that `path.dirname`

> Return the directory name of a path. Similar to the Unix dirname command.

but `require.main` is a module object itself, not a path.  Is this an undocumented feature of `path.dirname`?

---

Further information

For what it's worth, `require.main.filename` is a deep path to my global `gulp` install, which is nowhere near what I'm looking for.

I'm doing this so I can get a relative path **to** a root level `controllers` directory **from** my current node module, which might happen to be installed at any number of locations.  The final code to do this looks like this:

`path.relative(__dirname, path.resolve(path.dirname(require.main), "controllers"))`

*which works*, the purpose of this question is just to understand how `path.dirname` is working here, since it seems to be different than what the docs say.

**EDIT**

All that said, it looks like `path.resolve('.')` will in fact map out the path to my application root, `path.resolve('.', 'controllers')` will map out the path to my root controllers directory, and `path.relative(__dirname, path.resolve('.', "controllers"))` will map out the relative path from the current location to said controllers directory.

So all of this was more work than needed, but I am still curious why `path.dirname(require.main)` behaves as it does, and where that's documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a look at the function in the node repl.

```
var path = require('path');

path.dirname.toString();
```

> 'function (path) {\n  var result = posixSplitPath(path),\n      root = result[0],\n      dir = result[1];\n\n  if (!root && !dir) {\n    // No dirname whatsoever\n    return \'.\';\n  }\n\n  if (dir) {\n    // It has a dirname, strip trailing slash\n    dir = dir.substr(0, dir.length - 1);\n  }\n\n  return root + dir;\n}'

Formatted:

```
function (path) {
    var result = posixSplitPath(path),
    root = result[0],
    dir = result[1];

    if (!root && !dir) {
        // No dirname whatsoever
        return '.';
    }

    if (dir) {
        // It has a dirname, strip trailing slash
        dir = dir.substr(0, dir.length - 1);
    }
    return root + dir;

}
```

Looks like the posixSplitPath function returns an array. If the path isn't a string, an empty array is the result. ( A bit of speculation on the posixSplitPath function )

If the value of index 1, 2 are falsy, it defaults to `'.'`

#### libgen.h

I checkout out C's `libgen.h` and it has this to say about `dirname()`:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> > The dirname() function takes a pointer to a character string that contains a pathname, and returns a pointer to a string that is a pathname of the parent directory of that file. Trailing '/' characters in the path are not counted as part of the path.
> >
> > If path does not contain a '/', then dirname() returns a pointer to the string "." . If path is a null pointer or points to an empty string, dirname() returns a pointer to the string "." .
> >
> > This interface need not be reentrant.

Link here: [dirname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirname.html)

Answer (score 1):

`path.dirname({spoiled: 'beef'})` also returns '.'.

So does `path.dirname(7)`

Probably not what you want to be doing, eh? Even though it's giving an answer that looks tasty, it may not be good for you.

`path.dirname(require.main.filename)` is more useful.

EDIT:
I haven't checked the code, but it doesn't appear to be just an artifact of converting it to a string.

`path.dirname({foo: "cat/bar.baz"})` also returns "."

Comment: Turns out `require.main.filename` is pretty much useless - that winds up being the path to my global gulp install, at least when I'm running my tests (`gulp test`)